# Setting distance of header from top border and footer from bottom border

Tags: header-footer, margins

I am trying to set the header's distance from top border and the footer's distance from bottom border. They have to be both 1.25. 
Is this code correct? I don't want distance between text and header and bottom, I am setting the page's margins.

```
\geometry{headsep=1.25cm}
\geometry{footskip = -1.25cm}
```

Comment: No, you're probably looking for `\geometry{vmargin = 1.25cm}`.

Comment: Does it work for both?

Comment: `vmargin` sets the `v`ertical `margin`s, so the upper/top and lower/bottom. `\geometry{vmargin = 1.25cm}` is equivalent to setting them individually through `\geometry{top = 1.25cm, bottom = 1.25cm}`.

Comment: I used vmargin to set margins from top, bottom, left and right. My paper's instructions say that my document should have these page settings:
up margin: 3;  
down margin: 2.5;  
left margin 2.5;  
right margin: 2.5;  
header distance from border: 1.25;  
footer distance from border: 1.25;  

How can I do this?

Comment: It depends on the interpretation of "header distance from border" and "up margin"... we would need some clarity on what that means. Did they provide a visual?

Comment: No, they didn't. I literally have all I wrote here. That's also why I am so in difficult. I asked around but nobody could give more hints :(